# Skip section of characters using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have some incoming OData query information and I need to parse certain sections of the string to determine certain internal filtering techniques.

I have this regular expression

```
(?<LastWord>\A^[^\(]*|(eq|ne|gt|ge|lt|le|add|sub|mul|div|mod)|[-1$])
```

that  works on the following strings:

```
"startswith(tolower(columnName),'y') eq true" -- result is --> startswitheq
"endswith(tolower(columnName),'y') eq true"   -- result is --> endswitheq
"indexof(tolower(columnName),'y') ge 0"       -- result is --> indexofge
"indexof(tolower(columnName),'y') eq -1"      -- result is --> indexofeq-1
"tolower(Column) eq 'y'"                      -- result is --> tolowereq
"tolower(columnName) ne 'y'"                  -- result is --> tolowerne
```

The following string does not parse like the others:

```
"startswith(tolower(Column),'1') eq true" -- result is --> startswith1eq
```

It gets parsed to "startswith1eq", so I need help with the above regular expression to get it to skip the whole section from the beginning "(" to the last occurrence of ")", any suggestions?

Here is a .Net Fiddle with the current regular expressions and the failing item above:
[.Net Fiddle Code example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TPiAyV)

Thanks

Comment: Since RegExp implementations differ, it would help tremendously if you were to tell us on what platform or in which language you would like this to work.

Comment: It will help even more if you share with us the expected output for each input text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you meant to do a non-capturing group but did a "any of these".

```
(?<LastWord>\A^[^\(]*|(eq|ne|gt|ge|lt|le|add|sub|mul|div|mod)|(?:-1$))
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: this is the correct answer, would you mind detailing why such a small change as adding the ?: characters allowed the expression to search for the "-1" value but stopped it from allowing the back reference (finding "1" within the parenthesis), I think this may help the future researcher understand how you answered this.

Comment: @JohnMaloney: The `?:` wasn't the change. You had `[]` instead of `()`.

Comment: I have a slight issue with this regular expression, when the string between the parenthesis () has one of the item in the reg ex (i.e. eq|ne|gt|ge etc) it still picks them up, here is an example string: "startswith(tolower(wine),'1') eq true" the result finds the "ne" of the word "wine". How can I skip everything within all of the parenthesis, in other words the reg ex should never parse any of this "(tolower(wine),'1')" from the example. Thanks